# How SciPy calculates the p-value in pearsonr() function?

Tags: python, scipy, p-value

I have searched a lot but there is no explanation on how SciPy calculates the p-value for the correlation coefficient and why it is unreliable (started by SciPy on the function page) for data sets smaller than 500.

Comment: Looks like the docstring needs some work.  I created an issue for this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) computes the p value using the [*t* distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student's_t-distribution).  (You can check [the source code in the file `stats.py` on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/61efbf03d23fd3c4117f210becf6153c1cd6ddd9/scipy/stats/stats.py#L2942).)  This should definitely be mentioned in the docstring.

Here's an example.  First, import `pearsonr` and scipy's implementation of the t distribution:

```
In [334]: from scipy.stats import pearsonr, t as tdist
```

Define `x` and `y` for this example:

```
In [335]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])

In [336]: y = np.array([1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0, 4.1, 6.6])
```

Compute `r` and `p` for this data:

```
In [337]: r, p = pearsonr(x, y)

In [338]: r
Out[338]: 0.9739566302403544

In [339]: p
Out[339]: 0.0002073053505382502
```

Now compute `p` again, by first computing the t statistic, and then finding twice the survival function for that t value:

```
In [340]: df = len(x) - 2

In [341]: t = r * np.sqrt(df/(1 - r**2))

In [342]: 2*tdist.sf(t, df)  # This is the p value.
Out[342]: 0.0002073053505382502
```

We get the same p value, as expected.

I don't know the source of the statement "The p-values are not entirely reliable but are probably reasonable for datasets larger than 500 or so". If anyone knows a citable reference, it should be added to the `pearsonr` docstring.

Comment: in the github document in the example the firth r in the t distribution is squared and the fraction not square rooted, which may suggest the discrepancy? I know that your t-stat is the correct to use.